# Sharepoint 2010 Content Organizer Unknown Error

Tags: sharepoint-2010, workflow, uls

I am having an issue with SharePoint 2010 where the Content Organizer is giving an Unknown Error when we send a Document Set to the repository. Our workflows have not changed and after checking the ULS logs, we found this additional error message:

> System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldLookupValue.ParseLookupId(String fieldValue)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldLookupValue..ctor(String fieldValue)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUserValue..ctor(SPWeb web, String fieldValue)     at Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement.CommonUtility.GetUserFieldValueByLoginName(SPField fld, SPListItem item, Boolean dropSharePointGroups)     at Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement.CommonUtility.GetFieldValueAsString(SPListItem item, SPField fld, Boolean dropSharePointGroups)     at Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement.CommonUtility.GetFileSubmissionPropertyArray(SPListItem item, Boolean bIncludeAuditHistory, Boolean bUseFieldGuid, Boolean dropSharePointGroups)     at Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement.DocumentSets.DocumentSet.RgofpFromListItem(SPListItem item, SPOfficialFileAction postOp)     at Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement.DocumentSets.DocumentSet.SendToOfficialFile(String strRecordSeries, String& strAdditionalInfo, SPOfficialFileHost targetHost, String submitter, SPOfficialFileSubmissionMode submissionMode)     at Microsoft.Office.Workflow.Actions.SubmitDocSetActivity.Execute(ActivityExecutionContext context)     at System.Workflow.ComponentModel.ActivityExecutor`1.Execute(T activity, ActivityExecutionContext executionContext)     at System.Workflow.ComponentModel.ActivityExecutor`1.Execute(Activity activity, ActivityExecutionContext executionContext)     at System.Workflow.ComponentModel.ActivityExecutorOperation.Run(IWorkflowCoreRuntime workflowCoreRuntime)     at System.Workflow.Runtime.Scheduler.Run()

I only have a very basic understanding of the front end of SharePoint and workflows so I don't know what I'm looking at here. I see that there is a value that doesn't fall within the expected range, but I don't know what value it's referencing or how to change the value to place it in the expected range. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
Please try this fix....the error is in the workflow history logs. If you set the workflow auto cleanup timer job to 5min then wait for logs to clear out the history of deleted workflows the error will go away.

stsadm -o setproperty -pn job-workflow-autoclean -pv  "Every 5 minutes between 0 and
 59" -url http://yoursite
```